# Module Not Found No module named 'security' flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jwt

I am trying to login with **flask-jwt** but I am having problems when importing the *security* module,
the only install I've done to work with jwt was **pip install flask-jwt**. then I will leave the code, if you can help me I will be very grateful since I am just learning this micro-framework

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_jwt import JWT
from security import authenticate, identity

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "security_key"
jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(debug=True, port=5500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a module/file called `security` (e.g. `security.py`)?

The code in Flask-JWT quickstart example defines `authenticate` and `identity` methods: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/#quickstart

Comment: Not in the project I don't have any module called security.py.
But I already checked the documentation you sent me and following it to the letter I was able to authenticate.
Friend thank you very much for your help.